# How to run a child process after the main process ended

Tags: java, multithreading, process, fork

Hello !
I would like to create a child process which could run after the end of the main process in java (I did a simple schema of the execution I'd like : [result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDGDY.png). Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a child process from a process that is no longer running, so the child will have to be started beforehand.  And in that case, how will the child know the parent has terminated?

Your design is upside down. The "main work" should be done in a child, and the parent should sit there waiting for the child to terminate before it does whatever it needs to do.  That's an easy implementation and is a common design pattern.  It is, for example, what any Unix shell does to run an external program.

(I assume that when you say "process" that is what you mean - i.e., something in an entirely separate address space)

Comment: Actually I meant a thread.
I'm quite stuck because I'm working in a rest structure and I need to send the return result of the main thread before the child thread (which is started during the main) possibly terminate

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a simple response. I don't know why I was hesitating so much.

I'd just start a thread from my main fonction and according to my log, the thread continued after the principal treatment.

I'm guessing I have a daemon thread because the child is not killed.